# Locking Google Sheet Cells Monthly

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-dates

I am using Google Sheets, and my columns are set up for each month (Jan, Feb, March, etc). I have several rows that are pulling data from other tabs in the sheet to create an at a glance master list. I would like these rows to freeze on the last day of the month. ie. certain rows in the Jan column stop updating after Jan 31st. The February column stops updating after February 28th, etc.

The idea is that this master list can show me what the total was from the other tabs on the last day of the month. Any suggestions on what script I can use to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi and welcome. I'm sure you have a vivid understanding of what you are trying to achieve, unfortunately your question is unclear and lacks detail. You refer to "rows that are pulling data from other tabs in the sheet to create an at a glance master list" but you don't explain **how** they pull data, nor explain the other sheets, nor explain your understanding of a "master list". Would you please provide more written information about the "rows that pull information from other sheets" and also provide an example (table or screenshot or spreadsheet) of how this appears in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Here's an example of the sheet I am working off of with Monthly columns, and data getting pulled from other tabs to the master list.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qRVA6r_TWDWM3wmSvMdG5H5NmJ7-3rvJ9dx15mUo6rc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Meghan, does this question cover different ground than your other question [How to freeze Google Sheet columns based on date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/159981/196152)? If they are essentially the same, then I suggest that you delete this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to freeze Google Sheet columns based on date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159981/how-to-freeze-google-sheet-columns-based-on-date)